# Which type of RAM is supported in our servers?

Tags: dell, memory, dell-poweredge

I need to increase the RAM in our DELL servers. I tried using `lshw` to see what is already installed, but I cannot see if the RAM installed is a UDIMM or RDIMM.

```
Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: DIMM_A1 
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer: 00CE00B380CE
    Serial Number: 8244850B
    Asset Tag: 02103961
    Part Number: M393B5773CH0-CH9  

Handle 0x1101, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: DIMM_A2 
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer: 00CE00B380CE
    Serial Number: 8244855D
    Asset Tag: 02103961
    Part Number: M393B5773CH0-CH9  

Handle 0x1102, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: DIMM_A3 
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
    Manufacturer: 00CE00B380CE
    Serial Number: 8244853E
    Asset Tag: 02103961
    Part Number: M393B5773CH0-CH9
```

How can we find out which RAM to buy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could visit the [Dell Memory Selector](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/memconfig.aspx?~srd=true&c=us&cs=04&l=en&manufact=694&s=bsd&scat=prod&sk=ram&stype=1&family=PowerEdge%20Servers) and input your server model to see all of your options for the specific hardware.

You already have the information you need, though. The RAM listed in your `lshw` output is standard Samsung DDR3 *registered* SDRAM. It's a 2GB PC3-10600R/RDIMM module (Dell part `A4849697`).

If you wish to increase it, use the Dell part number `A2626093` for 4GB modules and `A4849724` for 8GB modules (or look for the generic equivalents).

A search on the manufacturer part number from `lshw` output clearly shows the RAM modules' specifications:

```
Manufacturer        Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
Manufacturer Part # M393B5773CH0-CH9
Memory Type         DDR3 SDRAM
Capacity            2GB
Pins                240 Pin
Bus Type            PC-10600
Error Correction    Registered ECC
Cycle Time          1.5ns
Cas                 CL9
Data Transfer Rate  1333Mhz
Memory Clock        166Mhz
Rank                Rank 1
Voltage             1.5
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Type the service tag number from the tag on the machine into support.dell.com. It will give you a detailed description of all parts that shipped with the server.

Comment: Hi @MDMarra is there a way to get the Service TAG code by shell?

Comment: try `dmidecode -s system-serial-number`